# automating firewall config deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

I wanted to develop a script (probably using Ruby) and with leveraging vendor provided REST APIs which should configure firewalls into Edge systems.

For example, these are various values I would need to read and use for configurations.

source:

destination:

port:

There would be several number of rules which includes different sources, destinations, ports to be mentioned in the file read. What would be the best way to save all this info and read by the script?

How are such deployments handled today using scripts? Sorry, I am quite new in automated deployments and scripting, could you please help with some pointers so that start with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use Chef - http://gettingstartedwithchef.com

There are many other tools out there for automated deployments and infrastructure provisioning. Here are some more I've encounted:

- Capistrano - http://capistranorb.com/
- Puppet - http://puppetlabs.com/
- AWS Cloud Formation or Elastic Beanstalk - http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation

Answer (score 0):

Well you might want to take a look at Capistrano which is what's generally used in the ruby world for deploying web applications:

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano

If you want something more generic, then you might want to investigate SSHKit (which is what Capistrano is built upon). SSHKit lets you deploy and run tasks on remote machines:

https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit